# Magento Enterprise 1.10 upgrade to Enterprise 1.14.1

Tags: magento, upgrade

my retail business is on Magento Enterprise 1.10 (from 2010) we want to upgrade to Magento Enterprise 1.14.1. Does anyone know what a reasonable time frame would be for this? We have about 150 SKU's on the site, and about 6 different extensions that we currently have installed. Also, is it necessary to upgrade to each version after 1.10, or can we upgrade directly to 1.14.1? Thank you!

Comment: Time frame can not be provided because it depends on how much you magento has been customized? But if you have only 150 sku and 6 extensions.It should not be very difficult to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The time frame depends on a lot of factors. Number of orders, customer accounts, attributes etc...
I'm guessing it's a smaller site, so it should not take more then an hour to upgrade. This is assuming you do not have thousands of registered customers and hundreds of thousands of orders.

The upgrade process will automatically run all the upgrade scripts in order for each version to 1.14.1

So you can go directly to 1.14.1

I would verify each module is compatible with 1.14.1 before proceeding.
If possible, I would copy the site to another server and do a test run to make sure everything goes smoothly.

Also always keep backups, always have an UNDO plan.